# How to compare strings to get missing word?

Tags: java, string, jtable

I have created a table and some buttons to remove/add rows.
Problem is, when I add a new row, I must insert a value in the field name which isn't already on that table. Let me explain.

Here is the default table:

[image: 11]

Now imagine i remove Station 3:

[image: 22]

If i add a new Station, I would want to add a new Station name Station 3 (which is missing on the list) but I am adding a new Station 5 (obviously as my code is not correct).

[image: 33]

My code for the Add Button action event is as such:

```
private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    String s2 = "";
    String s1 = "Station 1 Station 2 Station 3 Station 4 Station 5";
    int tb1rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
    if (tb1rows == 5) {
        // ERROR - MAXIMUM STATION NUMBER
    }
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<tb1rows;i++) {
            s2.concat(jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
            s2.concat(" ");
         }
        String[] s3=s2.split(" ");
        for (int i=0;i<s3.length;i++) {
            if (s1.contains(s3[i])) {
                System.err.println("contains");
                System.out.println(s3[i]);
            }
        }
        model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(),new Object[] {jTable1.getRowCount() + 1,"Station " + (jTable1.getRowCount()+1),10,false,0,Color.BLACK});
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my logic? Is there a better way to handle the problem so that I can get the "Station x" that is missing in that column so that I can re-add it?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: why all the string splitting/etc?  why not just start with an array of strings (if they need to be strings at all). alternatively you could simply have an integer field in that cell of the table, and use a TableCellRenderer to render the cell as `"Station " + val`

Comment: could you explain the TableCellRenderer method or maybe provide a link with example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of all that string manipulation, you could use set mainpulations:

```
HashSet<String> all = new HashSet<String>();
// then populate all with your 5 station strings (loop)
HashSet<String> have = new HashSet<String>();
// then populate all with the contents of your table (loop)
all.removeAll(have);
// all now contains the ones that weren't in the table.
```

Comment: I haven't yet worked with Set's, but will read further on and try it!

Comment: collections (and generics) are your friends!

Comment: thank you @John Gardner, that fixed my issue in a hurry!

I've marked it as the answer as I found this easy to understand to someone else who came across my question!

Answer (score 2):

So long as you have

```
"Station " + (jTable1.getRowCount()+1)
```

the new station is always going to be named "Station N + 1".

Assuming you fix the problem of splitting on a space described by another answer, your code should be something like

```
 for (int i=0;i<s3.length;i++) {
            if (s1.contains(s3[i])) {
                System.err.println("contains");
                System.out.println(s3[i]);
            }
            else {
 model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(),new Object[] {jTable1.getRowCount() + 1,"Station " + (i + 1)      ,10,false,0,Color.BLACK});
}

    }
```

Comment: Yes, as I stated, I know that line on the code ain't correct, but since I can't previously get the "Station x" that is missing I haven't changed that line yet.

My problem is how to find out the Station missing in that column.

Answer (score 2):

As there is a space in "Station 1" split on space won't do. Instead using another separator like ";", better use a `Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>()`.

Comment: I haven't yet worked with Set's, but will read further on and try it!

Answer (score 1):

if its ordered you can just find the first gap and insert there. so iterate over the rows and if `nextrow.numberInIt > thisrow+1` you insert `thisrow+1`

---

Code should be something like this:

```
int nextNrToInsert;

for(int=0; i < tb1rows; i++){
    thisrowNr = jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
    NextrowNr = jTable1.getValueAt(i+1,1).toString();

    if(nextrowNr > thisrowNr+1){
      //found the gap
      nextNrToInsert = thisrowNr+1;
      break;
    }
}
//change this to use nextNrToInsert
model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(),new Object[] {jTable1.getRowCount() + 1,"Station " + (jTable1.getRowCount()+1),10,false,0,Color.BLACK});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't quite understand your logic, can you please explain?

Comment: @LuisAfonsoTeixeira added some code, you want to find the gap so you look at the number of two rows and see if the difference is bigger than 1. But first you have to order the rows.

Comment: thank you for your time and answer, but I found it easier to deal with it using Collections!

Answer (score 0):

This line is the issue

`model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(),new Object[] {jTable1.getRowCount() + 1,"Station " + (jTable1.getRowCount()+1),10,false,0,Color.BLACK});`

You're always adding in the row with the `rowCount() + 1`. So even if you remove Station 3, there are 4 rows, and you're adding in row + 1.

Comment: Yes, as I stated, I know that line on the code ain't correct, but since I can't previously get the "Station x" that is missing I haven't changed that line yet.

My problem is how to find out the Station missing in that column.

Comment: @LuisAfonsoTeixeira You want to edit your question to make your question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This code has no effect:

```
    for (int i=0; i<tb1rows;i++) {
        s2.concat(jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
        s2.concat(" ");
     }
```

At loop exit, `s2` will still be an empty string, so `s3` will be an empty array.

But, the approach to concatenate strings and then split them is misguided, anyway. If all you need is find the lowest integer that, appended to "`Station`" will produce a unique string, the most natural approach is to make your own `TableModel` that uses a list of your own objects for each row's data. In that data you'll keep the integer itself, and not the entire string "Station *n*". Then it's going to be a trivial matter to find a hole in the list of integers.